# Is there a minimum/maximum length for an IDE cable?

Tags: ide-cable

OK I know you can't have unlimited length for these cables and that the newer rounded and shielded ones can be a little bit longer without "damaging" the signal.

So, is there a minimum/maximum length for the **flat** (ribbon) IDE cables? I need to know as I'm going to make a custom length one for a special project. Bonus rep if you tell for flat **and** rounded ones :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of people get this answer wrong.  They just look up what they see in Wikipedia and rehash it.  They will say the maximum length of an IDE cable is 18 inches.  However, this is not entirely true.  The maximum length is actually 18 inches from the IDE device to the IDE controller.  You can have a 36 inch cable, as long as the IDC connector at the 18 inch mark is connected to the IDE controller.  And this is ***not*** theoretical, as I have actually used a 36 inch cable with the connector in the middle.

Rounded IDE cables are just flat IDE cables that are folded and molded.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA):

> Parallel ATA only allows cable lengths up to 18 in (457 mm).

The minimum will be whatever is short enough to reach between the devices needed.